# How to add element to my jquery variable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add element to a variable like the following

```
$tooltipElement = $('#' + tooltipId);

//I want to edit p element inside the tooltipElement variable.
$tooltipElement.//<p>.css('font-size':'15');
```

How do I do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
$tooltipElement.find('p').css('font-size', '15');
```

Also, did you mean `15px`?